# strong type checking for user-defined types

Tags: c++, c++11, types, c++14, c++17

sometimes we using `using Key = uint32_t;` to define the new type.
The problem is - it is just alias. If you define two various types, they are not really type-checked:

```
using RowKey = uint32_t;
using ColKey = uint32_t;
std::map

<RowKey, std::map<ColKey, int>> myStorage;

RowKey keyR = 1;
ColKey keyC = 2;

int res1 = myStorage[keyR][keyC]; // it's ok
int res2 = myStorage[keyC][keyR]; // it's ok too, but it shouldn't compile!
```

A possible solution is to define a wrapper class around the int (or something else we have as key), but i think, this is overhead..

Is there any another solutions (maybe, in the new C++ standards)?

Comment: boost has a strong typedef, though I would also like to see a way that does not need boost...

Comment: Found duplicate by Googling "C++ strong type alias stack overflow". Please research before posting!!